# Singleton design pattern with double-check lock

Tags: c#, design-patterns, singleton

Consider you have the following code:
1. Why do we use double check lock, why single lock is not good enough, please provide detailed example.
2. What are the main drawbacks with this implementation? and how should I prove it?
Thanks.

```
 public sealed class SomeSingleton5  
{  
    private static SomeSingleton5 s_Instance = null;
    private static object s_LockObj = new Object();

    private SomeSingleton5() { }

    public static SomeSingleton5 Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (s_Instance == null)
            {
                lock (s_LockObj)
                {
                    if (s_Instance == null)
                    {
                        s_Instance = new SomeSingleton5();
                    }
                }
            }

            return s_Instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In .NET you don't have to use this pattern. The type system guarantees that a static field doesn't suffer from the race condition the double locking pattern tries to avoid. In Java it is different.

Comment: The second check is to take care of a race condition where, before `s_Instance` is initialized, two threads both access the getter.  Both threads evaluate `s_Instance` as null so _both_ proceed to the lock.  One will enter, initialize `s_Instance` and return.  The second thread will enter and if you do not have the second check, it will _reinitialize_ `s_Instance` and return a new instance.  Now the two threads will have two different instances of the singleton.

Comment: @ChrisSinclair: okay now it is clear, but I'm now wondering if this solution completely solve any race condition may occur, or we just solved the specific scenario you've mentioned. I cannot find away to map all the race conditions which may occur and therefore it is hard to understand why this solves all race conditions

Comment: Within the `lock`, the runtime guarantees that only 1 thread may execute at once.  So it's impossible to have any other race conditions.

Comment: The only reason I can think of to keep it is if you need to be able to destroy/recreate the singleton instance. In that case, you need to mirror the double-check lock in the destroy method, as well as keeping it in the singleton instance accessor.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think the best implementation of singleton class is provided by `Jon Skeet`.

```
public sealed class Singleton
{
  private static readonly Singleton instance = new Singleton();
  public static Singleton Instance { get { return instance; } }
  static Singleton() {}
  private Singleton() {}
}
```

> [Singleton by Jon Skeet Clarification](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Beforefieldinit.aspx)

Comment: This is indeed best approach. No locking is required. Only thing is that blank static constructor is mandatory required.

Comment: +1 Static initialization is indeed a very effective system for this :)

Comment: @Tilak: Why is a blank static constructor needed? Edit: Nevermind, found answers in the links :)

Comment: It is easy way to mitigate beforefieldinit effect. This is my understanding. http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Beforefieldinit.aspx. My understanding may not be 100% correct, but it does ensure consistent behavior.

Comment: @Asif: thanks but about my implementation, why are we doing double check (ifX2),  I really don't get its purpose

Answer (score 2):

1. Aquiring a lock is expensive. Without the first `if(s_Instance == null)` check, a lock would be aquired **each** time someone accesses the singleton. But a lock actually only needs to be there during instance *creation*. So the first `if(s_Instance == null)` prevents the unnecessary locking. The second `if(s_Instance == null)` needs to be there because initially two threads might have evaluated the first `if(s_Instance == null)` as `true` and the two threads would thereafter instanciate `s_Instance` after each other inside the lock.
2. I don't see any real drawbacks in your implementation but with the alternative (static constructor, see below) we have a solution that is simpler and involves less code. So it is more maintainable and less errorprone. Also it doesn't require locking at all. As mentioned earlier, locking is expensive.

you can improve it by using a static constructor:

```
public sealed class SomeSingleton5  
{  
    // the compiler will generate a static constructor containing the following code 
    // and the CLR will call it (once) before SomeSingleton5 is first acccessed
    private static SomeSingleton5 s_Instance = new SomeSingleton5();

    private SomeSingleton5() { }

    public static SomeSingleton5 Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return s_Instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks but about my implementation, why are we doing double check (ifX2),  I really don't get it's purpose