# How do I ensure only one instance of the object of the class is created?

Tags: c#, class

In my class A, I have a ZMQ object

```
    public void StartLogging(object connection)
    {
        var ctxt = new ZMQ.Context();
        var publisher = ctxt.Socket(ZMQ.SocketType.PUB);
        publisher.Bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5000");
        if (connection is uint)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("strange");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Class B will do something like

```
ClassA test=new ClassA();
```

Class C will also do something the same

```
ClassA test=new ClassA();
```

This will result in 2 ZMQ object being created binding to the same port which will result in error. How do I fix this problem?

Comment: Search for `singleton pattern`. And read http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx

Comment: Thanks. and Thanks to Usman Waheed too

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek is exactly right.  Jon's article is the best on the web for understanding singletons.  Let me know if you have any questions about my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A singleton is what you need.  [Jon Skeet's excellent article](http://csharpindepth.com/Articles/General/Singleton.aspx) will tell you more than you need to know.

In your case it might look something like this:

```
public void StartLogging(object connection)
{
    var ctxt = Singleton.Instance.Context();
    var publisher = ctxt.Socket(ZMQ.SocketType.PUB);
    publisher.Bind("tcp://127.0.0.1:5000");
    if (connection is uint)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("strange");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public sealed class Singleton
{
    private static readonly ZMQ instance = new ZMQ();

    // Explicit static constructor to tell C# compiler
    // not to mark type as beforefieldinit
    static Singleton()
    {
    }

    private Singleton()
    {
    }

    public static Singleton Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A [singleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11328186/singleton-design-pattern-with-double-check-lock) pattern would help you.

This works even for multi threaded application.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to

> singleton pattern

here is what MSDN has: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx